# A responsive two-column layout using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a small layout of sections

```css
.collection {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.collection section {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="collection">
  <section>
    <h2>bar</h2>
  </section>

  <section>
    <h3>baz</h3>
  </section>

  <section>
    <h1>FOO</h1>
  </section>
</div>
```

Then everything is positioned in one column. I'd expect such a layout

```
___________
| h2 |    |
|____| h1 |
|_h3_|____|
```

I know that the layout would wrap if I set `max-width`. But I don't know the `div` size in advance. My intent is to wrap in such a way that both columns have equal height.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Why not just handle it as two separate columns? Are they supposed to responsively collapse or something?

Comment: Yep, on a small screen they should become one column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By giving the `h1` section a 100% height, it will be forced into a new column.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.collection {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 100%;
}

.collection section {
    width: 50%;
    flex: 1;
    border: 1px dashed black;
}

.collection section:last-child {
    flex-basis: 100%;
}

@media ( max-width: 700px ) {
    .collection section { width: 100%; } 
    .collection section:last-child { flex-basis: auto; } 
}
```

```html
<div class="collection">
    <section><h2>bar</h2></section>
    <section><h3>baz</h3></section>
    <section><h1>FOO</h1></section>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e0adjabh/1/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it possible to adapt the solution so that it doesn't depend on elements used? For example: we now place three small elements of height 100px and two big elements of height 150px. With this solution, only one section will appear on the right while there's place for two.

Comment: You're welcome. For your modified layout, consider posting a new question with all the details.